# Scrape Meta data from another platform and put in wordpress site

Tags: php

I've recently built a site in wordpress and the original site was using `Travelize CMS` as backend. But in the original site there were meta data in all the pages which aren't currently available in the new built site. As there are many pages in the new site so it isn't possible to put them manually page by page. 
So I was wondering if there's any way to scrape the meta data from the old site and put them in the wordpress pages given that the urls are same for all pages?

Comment: What sort of meta data are you talking about?

Comment: mostly meta description @JacobPeattie